# Out of memory due to hash maps used in map-side aggregation

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, hiveql

MY Hive Query is throwing this exception.

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 6; number of reducers: 1
2013-05-22 12:08:32,634 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-05-22 12:09:19,984 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201305221200_0001 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_201305221200_0001_m_000007 (and more) from job job_201305221200_0001
Examining task ID: task_201305221200_0001_m_000003 (and more) from job job_201305221200_0001
Examining task ID: task_201305221200_0001_m_000001 (and more) from job job_201305221200_0001

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201305221200_0001_m_000001

URL:
  http://ip-10-134-7-119.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9100/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201305221200_0001&tipid=task_201305221200_0001_m_000001

Possible error:
  Out of memory due to hash maps used in map-side aggregation.

Solution:
  Currently hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory is set to 0.5. Try setting it to a lower value. i.e 'set hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory = 0.25;'
-----

Counters:
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask


    select 
        uri, 
        count(*) as hits 
    from
        iislog
    where 
        substr(cs_cookie,instr(cs_Cookie,'cwc'),30) like '%CWC%'
    and uri like '%.aspx%' 
    and logdate = '2013-02-07' 
    group by uri 
    order by hits Desc;
```

I tried this on 8 EMR core instances with 1 large master instance on 8Gb of data. First i tried with external table (location of data is path of s3). After that i downloaded data from S3 to EMR and used native hive tables. But in both of them i got the same error.

```
FYI, i am using regex serde to parse the iislogs.

'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
               WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
               "input.regex" ="([0-9-]+) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\".*\"|[^ ]*) ([0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+)",
               "output.format.string"="%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s %16$s %17$s %18$s %19$s %20$s %21$s %22$s %23$s %24$s %25$s %26$s %27$s %28$s %29$s %30$s %31$s %32$s")
location 's3://*******';
```

Comment: I only see a query, but you're saying there's an exception? Please include any details on the exception itself.

Comment: @LukasVermeer  Error was: Out of memory due to hash maps used in map-side aggregation....Although now, i have included the details

Answer (score 1):

- the location of the table doesn't matter to Hive.
- it would be better if you can paste the query - so one can figure out whether the mapper is sorting as well or not.

  in any case - we need to increase the amount of memory. check how much memory the map tasks are configured to run with (mapred.child...). should be at least about 1G. if that is large enough you can:

  - if mapper is not sorting: consider bumping the hash aggregate memory % as indicated in the log to a higher number
  - if mapper is sorting - just bump up task memory to a larger numer.

Comment: Thanks joydeep .....yes, my mapper is sorting.......i tried to debug the problem and it comes out that my mapper was using 5.5 gb of RAM. So, i increased the RAM and it worked. Before increasing the RAM i also tried set hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory = 0.25. But it didn't work.

Comment: i have one more question....let's say to decrease the uses of my memory it i configure two parameters to generate the compressed output. will it help to reduce the uses of RAM? mapred.compress.map.output=true
mapred.map.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `set hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory = 0.25;` as written in the message?
You can read more [here](http://dev.bizo.com/2013/02/map-side-aggregations-in-apache-hive.html)

Comment: Hi, sergey i have already looked into this link. it didn't help.